# null pointer exception in android

Tags: android

I am having a NullPointerException in my android code on this section

```
String title = titleEt.getText().toString();
String description = descriptionEt.getText().toString();
Log.i("title",title);
Log.i("description",description);

audioRecordPasser.onAudioRecordPass(title, "hiphop", description, fileUri.getPath());
getDialog().dismiss();
```

The exception is on the line

```
audioRecordPasser.onAudioRecordPass(title, "hiphop", description, fileUri.getPath());
```

audioRecordPasser is an interface.
The complete code implementation is

```
public class UploadFragment extends DialogFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, View.OnClickListener {
Spinner genres;
ImageView photo;
TextView submit;
String fileName = "";
EditText titleEt, descriptionEt;

private static final String KEY = "choice";

public Uri fileUri; // file url to store image/video

OnAudioRecordPass audioRecordPasser;

public UploadFragment(){

}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_upload, null);
    builder.setView(v);

    submit = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.upload_textView_submit);
    genres = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.upload_spinner_genre);
    photo = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.upload_imageView_photo);
    titleEt = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.upload_edittext_title);
    descriptionEt = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.upload_editText_description);

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            R.layout.ngoma_spinner, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.genres));
    dataAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    genres.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


    genres.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    submit.setOnClickListener(this);
    photo.setOnClickListener(this);
    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}

private static final int INT_CODE = 1;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.upload_textView_submit:
            Log.i("URI", fileUri.getPath());
            // audioRecordPasser.onAudioRecordPass(titleEt.getText().toString(),"hiphop",descriptionEt.getText().toString(),fileUri.getPath());

            if (validateInput()==false){
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Fields cannot be blank.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                String title = titleEt.getText().toString();
                String description = descriptionEt.getText().toString();

                Log.i("title",title);
                Log.i("description",description);

                audioRecordPasser.onAudioRecordPass(title, "hiphop", description, fileUri.getPath());
                getDialog().dismiss();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.upload_imageView_photo:
            UploadPhotoDialog uploadDialog = new UploadPhotoDialog();
            uploadDialog.setTargetFragment(this, INT_CODE);
            uploadDialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "uploadPhoto");
            break;
    }
}


/**
 * **************************************************************************************************
 */

private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;


/**
 * Select image from gallery
 */
private void selectFromGallery() {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
}

/**
 * Capturing Camera Image will lauch camera app requrest image capture
 */
private void captureImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}

/**
 * Here we store the file url as it will be null after returning from camera
 * app
 */

// directory name to store captured images and videos
private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "ngoma";


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // save file url in bundle as it will be null on screen orientation
    // changes
    outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
}

/*
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // get the file url
    fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
}*/

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // get the file url
    //fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
}

/**
 * Receiving activity result method will be called after closing the camera
 */
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if the result is capturing Image
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // successfully captured the image
            // display it in image view
            previewCapturedImage();
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // user cancelled Image capture
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // failed to capture image
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    } else if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK
            && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        fileUri = selectedImage;
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        // String picturePath contains the path of selected Image
        previewFromGallery(picturePath);
    }
}

/**
 * Display image from a path to ImageView
 */
private void previewCapturedImage() {
    try {

        // bimatp factory
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
        // images
        options.inSampleSize = 8;

        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
                options);

        Log.i("previewCapturedImage", fileUri.getPath());

        photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void previewFromGallery(String picturePath) {
    photo.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
}

/**
 * ------------ Helper Methods ----------------------
 * */

/**
 * Creating file uri to store image/video
 */
public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    fileUri = Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    Log.i("getOutputMediaFileUri", fileUri.getPath());
    return fileUri;
}

/**
 * returning image / video
 */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

    // External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Error creating "
                    + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory.");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}


public void choiceSelector(String data) {
    if (data.equalsIgnoreCase("camera")) {
        captureImage();
    } else if (data.equalsIgnoreCase("gallery")) {
        selectFromGallery();
    }
}



public interface OnAudioRecordPass {
    public void onAudioRecordPass(String title, String genre, String description, String photouri);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        audioRecordPasser = (OnAudioRecordPass) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnAudioRecordPass");
    }
}


private boolean validateInput() {
    if (titleEt.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("") || descriptionEt.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Everything runs fine.In my logcat, I can see the values of title and desription and fileUri.getPath() variables.What could be the issue?
The logcat content

```
10-31 15:42:44.032    4101-4101/ngoma.android.shimba.com.ngoma E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.shimba.android.ngoma.activities.MainActivity.onAudioRecordPass(MainActivity.java:516)
        at com.shimba.android.ngoma.fragments.UploadFragment.onClick(UploadFragment.java:101)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4440)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Where is your logcat error?

Comment: 2 ways to get this audioRecordPasser is null or fileUri path is null we cannot help you if you don't share more code !!!

Comment: Check this may be null `fileUri.getPath()`.

Comment: audioRecordPasser is not null because changing the method arguments to static strings makes the code run ok.

Comment: @StackFlowed I have added the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the parameter `fileUri.getPath()`
May be this is not properly initialized and as a result its value is `null`
Check the value of `fileUri` variable value before passing it to the function.
This will solve your problem